# When installing popplerqt5 using Dockerfile in Google Cloud Run container, No module named 'popplerqt5' error

Tags: python, docker, google-app-engine, google-cloud-run

I'm deploying an app to parse pdfs and return their highlighted content. After submitting my build and deploying it on cloud run, I ran into this error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'popplerqt5'

I previously ran into this error when running it python3 virtualenv on my local machine. However, I resolved it by running

> /usr/bin/python3 main.py

instead of

> python3 main.py

Currently I am running the app from my Dockerfile and am hence unable to pull of the same method. This is my Dockerfile configuration.

```
FROM gcr.io/google-appengine/python

# Create a virtualenv for dependencies. This isolates these packages from
# system-level packages.
# Use -p python3 or -p python3.7 to select python version. Default is version 2.
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install poppler-utils -y
RUN virtualenv -p python3 /env

# Setting these environment variables are the same as running
# source /env/bin/activate.
ENV VIRTUAL_ENV /env
ENV PATH /env/bin:$PATH

# Copy the application's requirements.txt and run pip to install all
# dependencies into the virtualenv.
RUN apt-get install -y python3-poppler-qt5
ADD requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install Flask gunicorn
RUN pip install -r /app/requirements.txt

# Add the application source code.
ADD . /app


# Run a WSGI server to serve the application. gunicorn must be declared as
# a dependency in requirements.txt.
CMD gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app
```

How do I get about this error?

Comment: You generally don't use virtual environments in Docker: the Docker image filesystem space is also isolated from the host's, so "system-level" packages in a container are still separate from host-Python packages.  That might help resolve some confusion around which Python and which libraries you're using.

Comment: @DavidMaze 
I have tried using python 3.7-slim without the virtualenv and still faced the same issue with poppler. Would there be a way for me to specify the python3 path from gunicorn?